# CI DataMapper: Find with No Related Objects

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

My CodeIgniter/DataMapper site needs to display a list of `categories`.  Each `category` has a many-to-many relationship with itself, for multiple parents/children.  I want to initially select *only the categories with with **no parents***, or in other words, with no objects connected through a specified relationship.

I've run through a couple of possibilities (like including the related object count in the select and adding it to the where clause, which doesn't work because WHERE is evaluated before generating the column values in SQL), but to no avail.

Advice?  Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you add the related count into a `having` clause? Maybe post your `$has_one` / `$has_many` parts of the classes, that would help to see how they got set up exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: compare the related objects ID to `NULL`.  If it's an integer auto-increment column, no values will actually be `NULL`, but if there are no related rows in the join, it will come out as `NULL`.

```
$c = new Category();

$top_level_categories = $c
    ->where_related_parents('id IS NULL')
    ->get();
```